# Serialization in a heterogenous environment

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, heterogeneous

In our project we have two parts: **webui** - runs on top of **.Net 4.5**, **msmq-listeners** - Windows services - they run on top of **.Net 3.5**.

To communicate between the applications we use the **MSMQ** queueing. I've seen many examples where (*de-*)*serialization* of the message body is perfomed using a shared (a separate assembly) **POCO**.

Is there any other way of doing the serialization desrialization instead of parsing the bodies as xml documents?

Comment: JSON is a possibility: https://gist.github.com/jchadwick/2430984

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at that!